# Losing php empty post entries

Tags: php, apache, post

I have a strange situation in one of my servers. Whenever I post a form that contains an empty value for a given post key, when I try to read that key from the $_POST array it is not set as expected.

I expect:

```
isset($_POST[$k]) == true
```

But I get:

```
isset($_POST[$k]) == false
```

I have not been able to find evidence of this problem anywhere else in the web.

I have two servers and in one of them it happens and in the other one it does not.

I have no idea if it could related to my version of PHP, or Apache, or some configuration file.

Test scenario:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST['param']);
?>
<form action="posttest.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="param[text1]" value="1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="param[text2]" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="param[text3]" value="3"><br>
    <input type="text" name="param[text4]" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="param[text5]" value="4"><br>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

### Server A (the good one)

Data:

- PHP Version 5.4.45

Echoes this:

```
[param] => Array
(
    [text1] => 1
    [text2] => 
    [text3] => 3
    [text4] => 
    [text5] => 4
)
```

### Server B (the faulty one)

Data:

- PHP Version 5.6.20

Echoes this:

```
[param] => Array
(
    [text1] => 1
    [text3] => 3
    [text5] => 4
)
```

I don't know what more info to add to the question, so if you have a clue and need more information please let me know and I will update the question

Comment: What version of PHP is running on those two servers?

Comment: If server B running Suhosin?

Comment: Check the configuration on both servers with `phpinfo();`

Comment: "*I have no idea if it could related to my version of PHP, or Apache, or some configuration file.*" Well, if you have no idea, then we *definitely* have no idea. You should probably volunteer that information.

Comment: Are you running on a PHP framework? If so then it's possible that it is preprocessing the `$_POST` data and unsetting empty values. If not then your symptoms are indicative of the `<input type="text">` being disabled.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, I was hoping to get ideas of how to find out. I will compare the two phpinfo results on both servers and post it here.

Comment: Both are using Apache

Comment: there is no framework involved, it is just the raw php file with a simple form post to itself.
I did some comparing between the two php info files and found this configuration with different values in both servers: always_populate_raw_post_data, I updated the question

Comment: So, did setting `always_populate_raw_post_data` on server B to the same value as server A fix the issue?

Comment: yes, both were disabled so I stopped looking in that direction. I had putt hat information in the question , but then I removed it because it is misleading for other people that might want to help solve the problem

Comment: I still have no solution, but the workaround is to use multi part form. This is less than ideal but it will do until I know what went on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has disappeared and it was after running an EasyApache on my WHM console. Maybe it was a misconfiguration or a bug in the php binary I was using, who knows.